# What does "kicking out" have to do with "shattered dreams"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please help me understand this sentence i.e what is the person who's writing this trying to say  and also tell me if this sentence is grammatically correct or not.

> The first time they kicked me out, they left me with nothing but shattered dreams.

What does this kicking out has to do with shattered dreams. I actually can't understand the tone of these lines i.e what actually these lines want to say together as a whole.

Comment: Without context, it's a little tricky to ascribe exact meaning. Possibly, the person being kicked out [evicted/fired from a job (got rid of)] finds that their hopes for the future of their staying wherever/for their career have been dashed, thereby shattering their dreams of could be.  Grammatically, it's ok, I believe.

Comment: Oh thank you for answering. But one more question is the sentence structured correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To kick out* usually means to throw out,[1](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/kick_out#Verb) but in this case, it looks like the speaker has specifically been kicked out of their home. This will likely be what *shattered their dreams*.[2](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/shattered#Adjective)

Comment: What about the sentence structure and grammar are those ok?

Comment: The sentence structure and grammar are perfectly fine.